# Unable to get the user-id/identity details from Log Analytics workspace captured from Serverless Pool SQLs

Tags: azure-log-analytics, usage-statistics, azure-synapse, serverless-architecture

I have

1. Azure Synapse Workspace on which I have Synapse Administrator access
2. Through Azure portal - I have configured he Log Analytics and running below KQL statement to find the list of queries executed along with data processed in MBs and user-id/identity of the SQL

I am not able to find the identity here - Is there a setting to fetch it ?

[image]

Below is the KQL statement

SynapseBuiltinSqlPoolRequestsEnded
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| evaluate bag_unpack(Properties)
| project startTime,endTime,error,Identity,queryText, command,dataProcessedBytes/1024/1024

Let me know, if this is a limitation at this moment or am I missing anything here ?

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Identity` column in `SynapseBuiltinSqlPoolRequestsEnded`. It has the login name of the user running the query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limitation for this.

Log analytics does not capture any PII(Personally identifiable information) for data compliance.