# Azure Log Analytics and PII or sensitive Data

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302107/unable-to-get-the-user-id-identity-details-from-log-analytics-workspace-captured)

It is stated that "Log analytics does not capture any PII"
But [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/personal-data-mgmt) it states otherwise. When enabled auditing the username was not visible in Log Analytics but when the same data was sent to storage account it was available there. So is Log Analalytics really messing up with sensitive data?

Comment: I think what we can do is trust what official document said. QAQ

Answer (score -1):

It's recommended to follow Microsoft documentation and you can always stop collection of, obfuscate, anonymize, or otherwise adjust the data being collected to exclude it from being considered PII.

Comment: What happens by default was the question